# Detecting Camera using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, photobooth

i am using `photobooth` js its working fine on localhost but when i am using on live server i am getting error **Please give `Photobooth` to use your Webcam. Try again in `Google Chrome`. Please let me know how can i resolve this problem.

[image]

**Javascript**

```
$( '#example' ).photobooth().on( "image", function( event, dataUrl ){
    $( "#gallery" ).show().html( '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" ><input type="hidden" id="imgdata" value="' + dataUrl + '" >');
});
```

Comment: Does the live server URL start with `https://` ?

Comment: https://github.com/WolframHempel/photobooth-js/issues/16